# Why do i get an literal array Error in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have a problem with the following QUERY code in Google Sheets. 
All rows work fine accept the first row. Column BY crashes the code. When i change the column to BZ it works fine, but that's not the data i need. What am i doing wrong?

The error i get:

Error
In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

```
QUERY({
        QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$CS$1051, "select A, BR, E, F, BT, BY, I, H");
        QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$CS$1051, "select A, BJ, E, F, BL, BQ, I, H");
        QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$CS$1051, "select A, BB, E, F, BD, BI, I, H");
        QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$CS$1051, "select A, AT, E, F, AV, BA, I, H");
        QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$CS$1051, "select A, AL, E, F, AN, AS, I, H");
        QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$CS$1051, "select A, AD, E, F, AF, AK, I, H");
        QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$CS$1051, "select A, V, E, F, X, AC, I, H");
        QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$CS$1051, "select A, N, E, F, P, U, I, H")
},"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7,Col8 WHERE Col2 is not null ORDER BY Col1")
```

Comment: What information is stored in the BY column? Give us a link, so I can help you find the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Client codes are stored in the BY column. Same as BT, BR, BQ en multiple others. 
Code format:  00000000X001NAA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BY` is a keyword for the query language. You have to escape it to use it as a parameter of your query. Use the backquote (`) symbol to escape the column name in your query formula:

```
=QUERY({
        QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$CS$1051, "select A, BR, E, F, BT, `BY`, I, H");
        QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$CS$1051, "select A, BJ, E, F, BL, BQ, I, H");
        QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$CS$1051, "select A, BB, E, F, BD, BI, I, H");
        QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$CS$1051, "select A, AT, E, F, AV, BA, I, H");
        QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$CS$1051, "select A, AL, E, F, AN, AS, I, H");
        QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$CS$1051, "select A, AD, E, F, AF, AK, I, H");
        QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$CS$1051, "select A, V, E, F, X, AC, I, H");
        QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$CS$1051, "select A, N, E, F, P, U, I, H")
},"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7,Col8 WHERE Col2 is not null ORDER BY Col1")
```